# How do you turn off subtitles in VLC for a video started from terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, vlc

I am opening a playlist for VLC from the terminal using `vlc *.mov`. I would like the playlist to start with subtitles turned off. I do not want to make that the default setting, I just want to pass an argument in the command that will start the videos without subtitles. Is this possible? I found `--key-subtitle-toggle <string>` in the `--help` docs but I don't know what string to pass. I have tried tried replacing string with several things such as `off`, `none`, `no`, `0`, `-1`, and `99` but to no avail.

How do I start these files in VLC from terminal and turn subtitles off at the same time?

Comment: I would assume you need the letter set to the hotkey: default that is "s". Use `--advanced` option to get met info in the help.

Comment: Ah, thank you. In the `--longhelp --advanced` I found instructions on specifying a specific subtitle track, `--sub-track <string>`, and when I set that string to a value higher than the available number of tracks in the folder, it shows the videos with no subtitles. It's not exactly what I was hoping to find but it is a usable work-around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `--no-sub-autodetect-file` option.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work. This is probably a more proper method than the one I came up with. Thank you.

Comment: yeah, it's the option to do exactly what you want to do,  so probably more proper than workarounds.  I found it with this ` vlc --help | grep 'subtitle' -C 10` command if you were wondering.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the argument `--sub-track <string>`, where `<string>` is a integer greater than the number of available subtitle tracks, effectively disables the subtitles. It's not the specific argument I was looking for but it is an effective workaround.

Comment: Did you try `0` and/or `-1`? [This](https://superuser.com/questions/533585/how-to-disable-subtitles-by-default-but-keep-them-available) and [this](https://wiki.videolan.org/VSG:Subtitles:Disable/) suggests this could be the solution…

Comment: Yes, I tried those first as I saw that they were options for disabling subs by default in the preferences. `0`, `-1`, `-10`, and `-100` did not work. I assume the first sub track is at position `0` in the list as `1` or anything higher disabled them and I only have 1 subtitle track in the file for each `.mov` now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a file with subtitles to test internal options, but I'd solve this by just sending the hotkey to disable hotkeys right after the start of `vlc`:

```
vlc --playlist-autostart /path/to/file & xdotool sleep 0.5 key s
```

You might need a different argument for the `sleep` option (it's time in seconds). Of course this works only when the file playback is started, so I added `--playlist-autostart` to immediately play the file.

Comment: Is `xdotool` 3rd party software? I have to be able to do this on different machines that I know all already have VLC but likely won't have much else that didn't come pre-installed with the 16.04 distro.

Comment: @JoshKesling It might be not preinstalled, but it sure is present in the repos.